# Seobility "Text Duplicate" error from separate mobile and desktop menus

Tags: duplicate-content, text

My website has 2 menus:
1 is used for mobile devices and the other for desktop devices.
When I test my SEO in "Seobility.net" I get the message "Text Duplicate". (Image attached)
Is there anything I can do to indicate to the spider that one menu is for mobile and one is for the desktop?
The mobile menu is located at top right of the website whereas the desktop menu is located at the side.
Here is the code:

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="h-nav">
          <div id="show-nav"><a href="#">Menu ☰</a></div>
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.tranquilhavens.com.au" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="dwarfmondo.html">Dwarf Mondo Grass</a></li>
            <li><a href="dwarfmondotrays.html">Dwarf Mondo Trays</a></li>
            <li><a href="koreangrass.html">Zoysia No Mow Pots</a></li>
            <li><a href="nomowgrasstrays.html">Zoysia No Mow Trays</a></li>
            <li><a href="dichondratrays.html">Dichondra Trays</a></li>
            <li><a href="thymemagiccarpettrays.html">Thyme Trays</a></li>
            <li><a href="corsicanminttrays.html">Corsican Mint Trays</a></li>
            <li><a href="zoysiaexperiment.html">Zoysia Experiment</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- END: header -->
        <div class="main clearfix">
          <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://www.tranquilhavens.com.au" class="current">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="dwarfmondo.html">Dwarf Mondo Grass</a></li>
              <li><a href="dwarfmondotrays.html">Dwarf Mondo Trays</a></li>
              <li><a href="koreangrass.html">Zoysia No Mow Pots</a></li>
              <li><a href="nomowgrasstrays.html">Zoysia No Mow Trays</a></li>
              <li><a href="dichondratrays.html">Dichondra Trays</a></li>
              <li><a href="thymemagiccarpettrays.html">Thyme Trays</a></li>
              <li><a href="corsicanminttrays.html">Corsican Mint Trays</a></li>
              <li><a href="zoysiaexperiment.html">Zoysia Experiment</a></li>
              <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- END: sidebar -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a serious error. It is merely an indication that some link texts are duplicated.

In this particular case it is because the menu is present twice in the source code. Once as a menu and once in the sidebar.
It also often happens that the menu is present once for desktop and once for mobile. However, this would be a rather poor implementation for the respinsiveness of a website.

All in all, it's not a big deal if the menu is present twice. But if you can avoid it, you should.

Comment: Thank you Dominik. I made the site myself but not real cluey with websites. Do you know who I could contact to remedy to problem? Cheers, Graeme

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you any direct contacts that can help you with this.
Bootstrap by twitter is a good framework for responsive sites and forums like this one offers a lot of help with the implementation.